# How to add a watch to a pointer value assignment in Visual Studio 2010 c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I have code like this:

```
nav->Value
```

How can I add a watch? Currently it says Unable to evaluate the expression.

Comment: Visual Studio watch is not very smart with overloaded operators.

Comment: That is depressing. Any idea how people typically see the value of the variable if the watch feature does not work?

Comment: Add `nav` to the watch, and look inside for where `Value` comes from and then right click it and add to watch. You could also try a newer version of VS.